# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in loadNamespace

Tags: r, rstudio

Al correr un programa instalando 'dplyr' me sale el siguiente mensaje

> ```
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in loadNamespace(j
> <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):  there
> is no package called ‘tidyselect’ In addition: Warning message:
> package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 3.5.3
> ```

Y al instalar  'tidyselect' el siguiente:

> ```
> Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =
> vI[[i]]) :    namespace 'rlang' 0.4.5 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.6 is
> required ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'tidyselect'
> * removing 'C:/Users/m_cle/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/tidyselect' In R CMD INSTALL Warning in install.packages :   installation of package
> ‘tidyselect’ had non-zero exit status
> ```

No se si a alguien le paso algo similar.